# How do I use startsWith method in stream with java?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to use stream for my code.

I have an entity class and this has a fields starts with 'abc' prefix.

Example:

```
private String abcTittlename;
```

and has a normal fields

Example:

```
private String titlePage;
```

And I am trying to use `startsWith` method for not starting 'abc',I want to write as fields that do not start with abc

How to I use this method or Is there another method I can do this in stream java? Please help me!

Comment: *I want to write as fields* what do you mean with that?

Comment: You want to send objects over the network, but only send fields beginning with some prefix

Comment: Now that you're entering the brave new world of Java [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), creating a stream and using `startsWith()` is suddenly the least of your problems.

Comment: Instead of using a name-prefix, you should better use annotations to mark those fields that should be transferred.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a class:

```
public class MyClass {
    private String abcTittlename; 
    private String titlePage;

    // other fields
}
```

You can use `Class#getDeclaredFields()` and `Arrays#stream()` to select all the fields that did not start with `abc`:

```
Arrays.stream(MyClass.class.getDeclaredFields())
    .filter(field -> !Modifier.isStatic(field.getModifiers())) // only include instance fields
    .filter(field -> !field.getName().startsWith("abc"))
    .forEach(field -> System.out.println(field.getName()))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply,but I want to not starting with 'abc' fields

Comment: @asme juste add a `!` in the condition, look post edited

Comment: @azro thanks for the edit, when writing I wasn't really sure what the OP exactly wanted

Comment: Please note that `getDeclaredFields` does NOT include the fields inherited from the super class. So if you want to include these fields to you will have to walk up the class hierarchy recursively.

Comment: @isnot2bad `getFields` should be enough. Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Thanks for replies I added a ! and solved.  I thought more complex :) @all

Comment: @Lino `getFields()` works recusively, but it won't return private fields. So it depends...

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question here is what you could do:

```
    // Create a new list to iterate over it later
    final List<Field> allFields = new ArrayList<>();
    // Add all fields from your desired class
    allFields.addAll(Arrays.asList(YourEntityClass.class.getDeclaredFields()));
    // Iterate over all fields
    final List<Field> filteredFields = allFields.stream()
                                                // Filter by any condition
                                                .filter(field -> !field.getName().startsWith("abc"))
                                                // Collect your filtered fields
                                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```